# изменения количества элементов в итераторе С++

Tags: c++, итераторы

Хочу разобраться с итераторами на С++, но не библиотечными, а собственными, написаными вручную, чтобы полнотью понимать принципы их работы. Основы я понимаю, но только по перебору. Хочу попросить обьяснить, возможно на примерах, как управлять, точней изменять, количество элементов в итераторе, добавлять новые или удалять уже имеющейся?

Собственно у меня есть такое задание:
Написать класс Студент сожержащий имя, номер зачетки и оценки, а так же класс Группа, содержащий список студентов. Сделать возможность добавлять нового студента в группу, удалять студентов у кого неучет, а так же обьеденять группы в одну.

Собственно не столь важно задание, а именно возможность изменять количество элементов в итераторе.

У меня есть такой код класса итератора:

```
using namespace std;

ifstream f_cin;
ofstream f_cout;

#define T Student

class iter
{
protected:
    T* i;
public:
    iter(T* i1) : i(i1){}
    iter(const iter& x) : i(x.i){}
    iter& operator=(const iter& x){ i = x.i; return *this; }
    T& operator*() const { return *i; }
    iter& operator++(){ ++i; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(const iter& x) const { return i != x.i; }
    friend int operator-(const iter& x, const iter& y) { return x.i - y.i; }
};
```

А так же класс контейнер Группа:

```
class Group
{
protected:
    T* ing;
    int size;
public:
    Group(int n = 1){ ing = new T[size = n];
    for (iter i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = T(); }
    Group(const Group& r)
    {
        ing = new T[size = r.size];
        for (iter i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = r.ing[i - begin()];
    }
    ~Group(){ delete []ing; }
    Group& operator=(const Group& a)
    {
        if (this != &a)
        {
            delete[]ing;
            ing = new T[size = a.size];
            for (iter i = begin(); i != end(); ++i) *i = a.ing[i - begin()];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Group& r)
    {
        for (iter i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) is >> *i;
        return is;
    }
    friend ifstream& operator>>(ifstream& ifs, Group& r)
    {
        for (iter i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) ifs >> *i;
        return ifs;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Group& r)
    {
        for (iter i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) os << *i << ' ';
        os << endl;
        return os;
    }
    friend ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ofs, Group& r)
    {
        for (iter i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) ofs << *i << ' ';
        ofs << endl;
        return ofs;
    }
    iter begin(){ return iter(ing); }
    iter end(){ return iter(ing + size); }
};
```

Помогите сделать функции добавления и вычитания, а еще лучше доходчиво обьяснить как они делаются, ведь главное не сделать задачу, а разобраться.

Comment: Нельзя изменить *у итератора* количество элементов, потому что. он их в себе не содержит. Элементы хранятся в контейнере, а итератор просто указывает на какой-то из них, позволяя с ним работать. Что вам именно нужно узнать, как добавить/удалить элементы, или как подправить после этого все существующие итераторы, чтобы те остались корректными?

Comment: скорее второе, чтоб можно было коректно работать с новым набором элементов, но и как грамотней добавить тоже неплохо бы узнать

Answer (score 0):

Тут действительно есть путаница в терминологии. В данном примере вы работаете с неразрывной областью памяти, начинающейся по адресу, хранимому в Strudent* ing, хранимом в экземпляре класса Group. Так же вам пришлось хранить число элементов для того, чтобы знать место, где эта область памяти закончится. Такая структура, если её отсоединимть от семантики группы студентов и оставить просто упорядоченную последовательность каких-либо объектов, называется вектором (std::vector). Кроме такого способа хранения даных есть ещё около десяти в стандартной библиотеке (std::set, std::list, std::deque и т.д.). Идея итераторов в том, что все эти структуры данных в конечном итоге хранят какой-то набор объектов и эти объекты можно перебрать. Как именно - многим алгоритмам не важно, важно просто иметь возможность последовательного доступа к элемментам. Для того, чтобы со всеми структурами можно было работать единообразно. т. е. алгоритм один но может работать с разными системами хранения данных.

Итератор в итоге указывает на какой-то конкретный объект в наборе элементов и знает как перейти к следующему (то, что у вас делает operator++), как правильно добавить элементв в такой ситуации? Если не искать приключений то никак. Дело в том, что эта операция связана с  управлением памятью (нужно добавить места в область памяти с которой вы работаете), а итератор этим не занимается. Память выделяет и освобождает Group, соответственно он и должен решать эту задачу. А вот для того, куда добавить этератор вполне годится, например можно написать метод в таком духе:

```
void insert(const Student& value, iter pos) {
    size++;//сначала увеличим размер массива на 1
    Student* newArray = new Student[size];//выделим новую память, в которую уместится наш увеличеный массив
    const iter newEnd(newArray + size);//это элемент следующий за последним, он будет служить для того, чтобы вовремя остановить алгоритм
    iter it(newArray);//это итератор с помощью которого мы будем двигаться по новому массиву
    iter oldIt = begin();//это итератор по старым данным
    //теперь скопируем все данные из старого массива в новый:
    while(it != newEnd) {
        if (oldIt == pos) {
            //если это место, куда надо вставить новый элемент то нужно скопировать новые данные
            *it = value;
            ++it;
        }
        if (it != newEnd) {
             *it = *oldIt;
        }
        ++it;
        ++oldIt;
    }
    //теперь освободим память от старых данных и сохраним указатель на новые:
    delete[] ing;
    ing = newArray;
}
```